# Create Encrypted Cookie using javascript that Laravel can decrypt

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cookies, laravel-5

Im trying to create an encrypted cookie using Javascript Code that Laravel can understand.

My current laravel project includes a pure JS code. In that JS code I displayed a JQVMAP.com Map and people click to define their country. In order to create a location cookie I included the following code:

```
setCookie(cookieName, code, 60); // minutes
```

The problem is that the value is created and stored in plain text -> EG: 'US'

But, For Laravel I need to create a cookie in the same way laravel encryption produce one, where 'US' data is represented like:

```
eyJpdiI6IjBlYlZqUU14ZWt4Q2FKUjNJd25BM.....
```

Honestly, despite the fact I read stackoverflow and google I was not able to find a way to do that.

any help appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the value? Anything you do using client-side JS can be modified by your end users. You can't trust it.

Comment: thank you @Chris , is not for security.. the problem is that laravel cannot interpretate the value if is not secured. I tried to include thata cookie in exceptions at Middleware\Encryptcookies.php but I have the same problem. thats why I asked. brgds

Comment: @Chris laravel guide: "All cookies created by the Laravel framework are encrypted and signed with an authentication code"  consequently when using {{Request::cookie('cookie name')}} no value is retrieved if its in plain text

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Laravel, but it should let you use plain PHP like Symfony does.  In that case you could just read the cookie with the PHP $_COOKIE variable.

Alternatively you could use an ajax call to Laravel and let it set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the PHP framework like Laravel, Phalcon etc. are using base64 encode/decode method to secure cookie value. Because base64 method is the only two way encryption, which means you can get the actual value/string once you encrype, which another meaning is you can decrypt the value to the actual value.

So, look for the Laravel source code what method they are using. If it is base64, then you can use javascript base64 encryption/decryption function to secure the cookie value before store to it.